# How to invoke Emacs from MS DOS prompt with a function with argument?

Tags: microsoft-windows, invocation

Inspired by the question [Launch emacs with ediff-files (of ediff-directories) from command line](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3618/2609) and the answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3623/2609, I tried

`emacs --eval '(set-background-color "green")'`

from an MS DOS prompt without sucess. What is wrong with this? I also tried with the argument `-Q` but it doesn't change.
I should mention that it works well if I execute it from an eshell inside emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOS does not recognize `' '` as quotes.

You will have to use the following:

```
emacs --eval "(set-background-color \"green\")"
```

Powershell works a little closer to what you expect:

```
emacs --eval '(set-background-color \"green\")'
```

But it too requires `\` before the `"` to properly escape them.